# Send Email from one address server to another server using Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an online form that allows users to email a complaint to the company. To test it I have used  gmail smtp as my host. I have no problem receiving the message to the designated email account when the sender is also a gmail but I want the "From" to not be limited to just gmail accounts. It appears that smtp is only good for sending emails from the same server?

Example: My form works great if the from is abc@gmail.com and the company email is company@gmail.com.

However if xyz@yahoo.com is entered for the sender, the receiver company@gmail.com never gets it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide my code as well if that is needed.

Comment: It would probably arrive as spam, maybe due to being suspected as phishing.

Comment: You could always just use a different relay. Google is pretty strict on preventing spam through its servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I was only using gmail to test but the real form will use Microsoft Outlook. Do you know if Outlook allows you to send emails from other servers like hotmail, yahoo, gmail, to the company's outlook address?

Comment: Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. Is SMTP even the correct approach? The form is filled out with the users email address and message, then emailed to the company. I might be mistaken in thinking that SMTP can be used to receive email.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a common security restriction when using SMTP.  Outgoing SMTP email can only contain a "mail from" address belonging to the sender.  If you break this rule, your email may be considered SPAM.

The following will allow your recipient to reply to an alternate address.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.from", "abc@gmail.com");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
m.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("xyz@yahoo.com"));
m.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("xyz@yahoo.com"));
```

See also

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/
- http://www.openspf.org/Best_Practices/Webgenerated

Comment: Sorry, I did a bunch of edits.  I had trouble remembering how to do this properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. So this will make the "From" equal to the sender's email? What I'm looking for is to have the sender's email that they entered in my form to be set in the "From" field of the Microsoft outlook email account.

Comment: In response to your comment, I updated my answer.  This will set the reply-to and from headers to yahoo.com address, but the SMTP "mail from" field will use the gmail.com address.  Again, it's been a long time since I've done this, but I've had to solve your exact issue in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to own the other email as well as set it to work with gmail,
Check [here](http://wonkabar.org/2009/09/02/gmail-smtp-custom-from-email-address/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to send the message to your company's mail server using the identity of the user who owns the application on the server, and include the information that the customer provides in the online form as data in the message you send.  The message won't look like it came from the customer, but then it really didn't come from the customer since it wasn't sent using the customer's mail server.

Comment: Bill this is a good point and the route I have decided to take. I am doing an upgrade on their system and they were doing it the other way. I am curious how this was accomplished but for the sake of not hacking the code, I will do the way you suggested.